# Vanilla forums not recognizing my ProxyConnect SSO

Tags: php, forum

I'm trying to implement single sign on integration with Vanilla forums, as described on [this page](http://vanillaforums.org/page/ProxyConnect_SSO). I'm using [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) with [Tank auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), but I understand that this method is not specific to any framework.

Both my site and the copy of Vanilla forums I have are hosted locally, so they share the same domain (localhost), which is a requirement for this method. I wrote some PHP code that should output the information needed by ProxyConnect's "AuthenticateUrl":

```
$id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
if($id===false) return;

$user = $this->tank_auth->user();
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo "UniqueID=$id";
echo "\nName=" . $user->username;
echo "\nEmail=" . $user->email;
```

If I'm signed in to my site, it outputs the following:

```
UniqueID=1
Name=hassan
Email=something@somewhere.com
```

This looks good to me. When I try to get Vanilla to use this to authenticate users, it doesn't work. It gives me a very generic error message:

```
Bonk
Something funky happened. Please bear with us while we iron out the kinks.
```

Not very descriptive. When I checked the error log, I see this entry:

```
File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/applications,
referer: http://localhost/vanilla/index.php?p=/settings/proxyconnect/test
```

Is this a bug with ProxyConnect, or is the above output malformed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mime type on the authenticate url is set to plain/text. I get it working in test mode but it doesn't work on the real forum.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, I didn't get it to work yet, but the header is being set to plain text.

Comment: Ok -- I get mine working intermittently in live environment, still not sure why it doesn't work sometimes. I think there's a bug somewhere hiding. Make sure user's login names aren't the same, and use DEBUG = TRUE to find the bugs in your code (Vanilla hides them all)